# Proof $E|\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu)|^4 = nE|X_i-\mu|^4+3n(n-1) \sigma^4$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ independent and identically distributed random variables.

With mean = $\mu$ and $E[(X_i-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2$ proof that:

$E|\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu)|^4 = nE|X_i-\mu|^4+3n(n-1) \sigma^4$

**UPDATE**

I have this:

$E|\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu)|^4 $
$= E|(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)-n\mu)|^4 $
$= E[n^4\mu^4-4n^3\mu^3\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i+6n^2\mu^2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2-4n\mu(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^3+(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^4 ]$
$= n^4\mu^4+E[-4n^3\mu^3\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i+6n^2\mu^2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2-4n\mu(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^3+(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^4 ]$

And then whats next?

Comment: $|x|^4=x^4$. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NCh I updated with what I have, there's where I'm stuck.

Comment: You have initially pretty summands $(X_i-\mu)$. They have zero expectations and the second moment given. What for did you merge them into very bad summands $X_i$ and $\mu$?

Comment: @NCh so how do I start?

Comment: Take initial sum to the power 4.

Comment: @NCh something like this $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu)\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu)\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu)\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu))$ or how so?

Comment: Let $Y_i=X_i-\mu$. Find $(Y_1+\ldots+Y_n)^4$ and take expectation.